# Take value from PHP function [the_time('HH:MM')] and change it based on selection in dropdown box with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, element

Is this possible? I return the time that something was posted via PHP function from the database and adjust it based on timezone data selected in a drop down box with Javascript on the client side.

For example: The PHP would return 5:00 PM GMT as the time, and if they selected EST it would subtract 5 hours from the time automagically.

Addendum: I just need to be able to, using a value in a drop box, deduct a numeric value from the returned time variable and display it in the users browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Javascript Date function? Pass the date to JS and then change it based on your dropdown select.

http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but every time the page refreshes the time zone information will be lost. You should probably use the server-side `$_SESSION` to store the timezone, and when it's displayed to the user account for the difference in PHP.

Comment: The problem is that we do not have a user account nor $_SESSION to utilize. Instead, I have a script to detect and populate the default value of the dropdown box with the users timezone.

Comment: Can you not also pull the time along with the timezone if you already have a script that gets the timezone?

Comment: Yeah, I could pull the users local time, but I need to change the time articles were posted based on the individual users timezone.